# Using list comprehension to keep items not in second list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, not-operator

I am trying to use list comprehension to remove a number of items from a list by just keeping those not specified.

For example if I have 2 lists `a = [1,3,5,7,10]` and `b = [2,4]` I want to keep all items from `a` that are not at an index corresponding to a number in `b`.

Now, I tried to use `y = [a[x] for x not in b]` but this produces a SyntaxError.

`y = [a[x] for x in b]` works fine and keeps just exact the elements that i want removed.

So how do I achieve this? And on a side note, is this a good way to do it or should I use `del`?

Comment: You mean this? `[x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i not in b]`

Comment: and yes, it is, and no, you shouldn't ;)

Comment: `in` is part of the list comprehension syntax, not the `in` operator, and so can't simply be replaced by `not in`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and look up indexes in `b`:

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10]
>>> b = [2, 4]
>>> [item for index, item in enumerate(a) if index not in b]
[1, 3, 7]
```

Note that to improve the lookup time, better have the `b` as a *set* instead of a list. [Lookups into sets are `O(1)` on average](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) while in a list - `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you're looking for somthing like :

```
[ x  for x  in a if a.index(x) not in b  ]
```

Or, using filter:

```
filter(lambda x : a.index(x) not in b , a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
   [j for i,j in enumerate(a) if i not in b ]
```

Answer (score -1):

after this:

```
y = [a[x] for x in b]
```

just add:

```
for x in y:
    a.remove(x)
```

then you end up with a stripped down list in a

Comment: `remove` removes the first occurrence of an element, not necessarily the one you want removed.